# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[AVCaptureDevice]'

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swift4

I am working on giving my app camera capabilities. I was following a tutorial (AppCoda: https://www.appcoda.com/avfoundation-swift-guide/). I have looked at other S.O. answers and have learned that the right side of the statement(below) must be an optional for the error to be solved. How would I make it an optional and fix the error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional allows you to have a nil in a variable. Then the compiler forces you to check if there is a value before you can use a variable. However, if you don't have an optional, that's a good thing for you - you don't have to check for the value cause it is ensured that there always will be one.

Therefore in your case you don't want an optional there, rewrite your code as follows:

```
let cameras = session.devices.flatMap { $0 }
guard !cameras.isEmpty else { throw CameraControllerError.noCamerasAvailable }
```

Because obviously the call `session.devices.flatMap { $0 }` return an array `[AVCaptureDevice]`, not an optional array `[AVCaptureDevice]?`. Therefore the compiler can guarantee that the cameras will always have an array value, and never a nil. Thus you can just guard against the empty array which would mean that there are no cameras (cause the list of cameras is empty).

Comment: I think you forgot an else statement between .isEmpty and {